# Cassandra Nods are exposing different and uncomplete metrics to Graphite

Tags: cassandra, graphite, grafana

I have set up Cassandra to report metrics to Graphite following these steps: https://www.pythian.com/blog/monitoring-apache-cassandra-metrics-graphite-grafana/ .

- I have not altered the graphite configuration (`metrics_reporter_graphite.yaml` in the tutorial) except the ip of my server .
- I am also using `metrics-graphite-3.1.2` instead of the proposed
  `metrics-graphite-2.2.0` because Cassandra could not start with the
  2.2.0 version.
- I am using Cassandra 3.0.8

The metrics seem to get sent to my Graphite server but somehow the Cassandra nodes expose different metrics. Also, the metrics are not fully submitted.

I took a Screenshot from the Graphite Web UI. Node `b19` has different metrics than the node `b30` for example. The second thing is that for the `Metric ClientRequest -> Latency -> Read` is missing a lot of attributes when comparing to visualvm (second screenshot).

[image]

[image]

How to get the full set of metrics for every node? Is there something I am missing?

Comment: Cassandra outputs a lot of metrics and without a beefy graphite server/disk can lose metrics. What kind of system do you have for graphite? ssd?

Comment: @ChrisLohfink I see. I'm using a normal HDD on the server that runs graphite. So I have to edit the configuration and let cassandra only expose for example all ClientRequest.* metrics?

Comment: the ClientRequest is a good starting point. Its the coordinator latency so if anything (other than `client->cassandra` network latency) is bad it would eventually show up there.